# Set up SFTP/FTP for development purposes

Tags: 18.04, ftp, sftp

1. I have 18.04 Ubuntu Server running (via VM) and using it for development (Mongo, Express, Node) purposes
2. I would like to introduce some code others have written. Some of it
   I can install via npm, others are available on Github
3. What is the best way I can incorporate such code into my application?
4. Suppose I need to download the code onto my host computer, then transfer it to my server, what is the simplest way I can set up this transfer mechanism. I have permitted root login but it seems it only works for SSH, but SFTP transfers always fails (though I can see the files).

Comment: Are you essentially asking how to set up SSH and SFTP? Or are you asking for help troubleshooting? Or are you asking something else? I don't see a clear question. SSH root login enabled seems an unwise habit.

Comment: I'm asking for help on how to set up FTP or equivalent. 

I am able to SSH via PuTTy. I managed to use FileZilla to log into my server. As a normal user, I can upload files without issue. If I log in as root, I can only view files but cannot upload them.

By the way, noted on SSH root login. I am doing this for convenience but I am just learning at the moment (please pardon my very silly question). My Ubuntu Server is just hosted via VM which I only switch on when I need it. Thank you.

Comment: How to set up an FTP server: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ftp-server.html. Personally, I use [SSHFS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS), but it's really just a matter of personal taste. It's not clear what file transfers your application needs to do, but applications should simply use wget/curl/aria2c with proper login credential.